# how to come up with a function with two input and an output

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a set of function inputs and output but I can't figure out how to get the function.

(The data came from some kind of puzzle that counts combination)

```
f(1,1)=1 f(1,2)=2 f(1,3)=3 f(1,4)=4

f(2,1)=1 f(2,2)=3 f(2,3)=6 f(2,4)=10

f(3,1)=1 f(3,2)=4 f(3,3)=10 f(3,4)=20

f(4,1)=1 f(4,2)=5 F(4,3)=15
```

I do notice the difference between row and column have some kind of pattern, but I have no idea how to put out a function of f(x,y). How should I solve a problem like this? Is this like a pre-calculus level question? I need to re-study my math...

Edit: I think I should give out the puzzle detail.

x is the amount of number and y is amount of [],
the function calculate the possible combination of [] and number.

e.g. x=2 y=2, we can have:

```
[12][] [][12] [1][2]
```

hence f(2,2)=3. The order of number can't be switched.

Comment: Looks an awful lot like Pascal's triangle, is $f(3,4) = 20$?

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking!

Comment: I updated my question. I might have miscount a number since I put out the combination by hand. Let me double check...

Comment: actually it is 20, I miscount a combination. so it is Pascal's triangle all alone...! Urgh! my muddy mind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's Pascal's triangle, but why?

Because it's stars and bars.  Since the numbers stay ordered, we can treat them as $x$ stars, and since the numbers need to occur within brackets, you can treat each $][$ as a bar that can be placed next to each other and at the ends, and you have $y-1$ of those.

OK, so we basically have $x+y-1$ places to put $x$ stars and $y-1$ bars, which thus can be done in:

$$f(x,y)={{x+y-1} \choose x}$$

ways.

Comment: Thank you! I have never heard of stars and bars before so I looked it up. Learned a lot today!

Comment: @Xolot You're welcome! :)